# What is Ghazwa-e-Hind?

Tags: hadith, war

What is Ghazwa-e-Hind? Is it authentic according to Islam?

Comment: Why this is off topic @Medi1Saif? This is a Hadis and I am asking how strong is this.

Comment: Simply speaking there was no clue in your post saying it is a hadith, and your post looked like a misuse of Islam for political reasons.

Comment: I didn't know whether it was in hadith or not or if so then how strong. That is why I asked. Actually I wanted to know whether it is a misuse of Islam for political reasons or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ghazwatul Hind is a prophecy that occurs in various hadith, such as:

- > عن ثوبان مولى رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم قال قال رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم عصابتان من أمتي أحرزهما الله من النار **عصابة تغزو الهند** وعصابة تكون مع عيسى ابن مريم عليهما السلام
  >
  > It was narrated that Thawban, the freed slave of the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ), said:
  >
  > The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: 'There are two groups of my Ummah whom Allah will free from the Fire: **The group that invades India**, and the group that will be with 'Isa bin Maryam, peace be upon him.'

  This has been recorded in, for example: [Sunan Nasai , كتاب الجهاد](https://sunnah.com/nasai/25/91) and [Sunan Al-Kubra  كتاب السير   - باب ما جاء في قتال الهند](https://shamela.ws/book/7861/21169#p1)  and [Musnad Ahmad ,ومن حديث ثوبان, Number 22396](https://al-maktaba.org/book/13157/22842#p1) and [Bukhari's Tarikh al-Kabir](https://shamela.ws/book/956/2309#p1) etc.

  It was classed as Sahih by al-Albani, see **[صحيح وضعيف سنن النسائي](https://al-maktaba.org/book/783/3247#p1)** and  [**سلسلة الأحاديث الصحيحة**](https://shamela.ws/book/9442/2764#p1)
- > عن أبي هريرة رضي الله عنه ، قال : وعدنا رسول الله صلى الله عليه وآله وسلم **غزوة الهند** ، فإن استشهدت كنت من خير الشهداء ، وإن رجعت فأنا أبو هريرة المحرر
  >
  > It was narrated that Abu Hurairah said:
  >
  > The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) promised us that **we would invade India**.  [ If I live to see that, I will sacrifice myself and my wealth. ] If I am killed, I will be one of the best of the martyrs, and if I come back, I will be Abu Hurairah Al-Muharrar.

  This has been recorded in, for example: [Sunan Nasai , كتاب الجهاد](http://sunnah.com/nasai/25/89)
  and  [Mustadrak al-Hakim,  كتاب معرفة الصحابة -  ذكر أبي هريرة](https://shamela.ws/book/2266/6741#p1)  and [Musnad Ahmad , 7128 - مسند أبي هريرة رضي الله عنه](https://al-maktaba.org/book/13157/7005#p1)   and [Sunan Al-Kubra  كتاب السير   - باب ما جاء في قتال الهند](https://shamela.ws/book/7861/21168#p1) and [Bukhari's Tarikh al-Kabir](https://shamela.ws/book/956/710) etc.

  It was classed as Sahih by Ahmad Muhammad Shakir, see his [commentary on the  Hadith of Musnad Ahmad](https://shamela.ws/book/98139/3326#p1). It should be Sahih according to Hakim. It is Hasan according to the commentary on [الجهاد لابن أبي عاصم](https://archive.org/stream/waq36636/36636#page/n667)

Comment: After reading your answer I have a lot of questions regarding this. India never attacked Arab(let alone during the time of Prophet Muhammad (PBUH)) then why Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) wanted to invade India and saying it's follower that they will be free from hell fire if they invade India? Contradicting the meaning of Islam.

Comment: @SantanuDebnath you may consider asking that as a new question. IMO this hadith will be qualified as a prophecy that one day Muslims would reach and invade india.

Comment: That may be true as some scholars consider that Ghazwa-e-Hind already happened as India was under Muslim rulers during 12th century. I am looking forward for your view on this matter @Medi1Saif

Comment: @SantanuDebnath IMHO there is no consensus among the ulema that Ghazwa e Hind has already occurred. What took place was rulers from Central Asia who happened to be Muslims invaded India through Sindh not for Islam but to gain access to the riches of India. It was done for worldly gains. Also please remember Islam had entered India in the 7th century through Kerala long before any invasion took place in present day Pakistan (Sindh).

Comment: @SantanuDebnath What the above Hadith seems to imply is that the group that invades India will be similar to the group that is with Jesus during his coming i.e they will righteous people who are mostly likely trying to free a land from a tyrannical leadership (similar to how Jesus is going to free people from the AntiChrist & the tribes of Gog & Magog)

Comment: But wouldn't that also put Muslims living in India in a difficult position, for Prophet Muhammad stated, “Love of one's country is a part of faith”. So what wins? Love of ones country or invading India? Also, if a follower of Islam is religion bound to invade India, logistically, it might be easy to make Muslims leave India and then fight the enemy that is outside the nation. Like many things, this just keeps getting confusing.

Comment: @happybuddha The quote you have mentioned is fabricated. And even if it is accepted then 'country' means land and not the government - it means love for the location and does not mean loyalty to the people ruling over it. Invading consists of defeating and removing the disbelievers from power and establishing Islamic rule over it.

Comment: @UmH - so there is no confusion then, a Muslim is religion bound to establish Dar al-Islam, which is the whole purpose of Ghazwatul Hind, by any means possible in India? If so, then Islam isn't really a religion of peace that it keeps beating its chest about, but infact a religion of violence?